# attribute with multiple treatment (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, attributes, sum, attr

I have a `System` class with an attr called `price` and a `Subsystem` class (`belongs_to :system`) with also this `price` attr.

The problem is in my model, because I have two different ways of treating the `system.price`

1) The system has at least one subsystem (`!system.subsystems.empty?`): I want the price to be the sum of all it's subsystems prices. In that case, my model has it's method price with a loop to sum the subsystems prices.

2) The system doesn't have ANY subsystem (`system.subsystems.empty?`): The price is simply an input field which it's filled in a form.

The trouble i'm facing is how to 'choose' which way to follow...

Can anyone help me? Thks a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply overwrite the price method in your model:

```
def price
  if subsystems.empty? 
    self.attributes["price"] 
  else
    subsystems.map(&:price).sum
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always just store the System's price somewhere else, and choose to use it whenever necessary:

```
class System

  has_many :subsystems

  def price
    subsystems.empty? system_price : subsystems.sum('price')
  end

  def system_price
    # maybe an active record attribute, this method might not exist
    25.00
  end

end
```